# how to show an overlapping view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a view with some UI components and a button on it, upon touch of a button I want to show a half view with some textfields on it overlapping the initial view, the initial view should be visible partly , the overlapping view will cover only half screen from bottom. Is this possible ?

I don't have any code as I am unable to figure out what it needs to be done, as we show any view it covers the entire screen.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried? You say "as we show any view it covers the entire screen" but how are you showing views? Are you adding subviews, using container view controllers to nest multiple view controllers' views, presenting view controllers as modals?

Comment: Yep i was showing it using view controller logic but i can see several answers which are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are several ways you can do this, here are two:

1) add a popover controller that gets displayed on your button press:
   here's some apple documentation on popovers: https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/Popovers.html

2) add the new view as a subview to your UIViewController
   
   PROGRAMICALLY:
   in the viewDidLoad function you can do the following to initialize the halfScreenView
   `GLfloat topOffset = self.view.frame.size.height/2;`
   `UIView halfScreenView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, topOffset , [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - topOffset)`
   `[self.view addSubview:halfScreenView];`
   
-more logic might be needed if you support Landscape orientation, you can always re-assign the location of the view with halfScreenView.frame.origin and halfScreenView.frame.size

-initially you can have this view be hidden
   halfScreenView.hidden = YES;

-when you click the button it will show the overlaying view:
   halfScreenView.hidden = NO;

USING STORYBOARD:
   you can also set up your overlaying view in the storyboard if you have one
  -drag a UIView into your UIViewController and set it up where you want it to be located 
  -initialize the view to be hidden by checking the hidden box in the attribute inspector
  -add the view as a property to your view 
  -manage when to show this view with self.halfScreenView.hidden
  -this technique allows you to customize what is inside the new view within the storyboard which is nice

FOR BOTH:
   -be careful with layers, you don't want your view to show up behind the one you already present. In the storyboard the last thing inserted goes on top. With in the code you can always access/change the views z position with halfScreenView.layer.zPosition (higher z values are on top)

Answer (score 1):

First create a new class subclassing `UIViewController` called SecondView (or whatever you want), then design the UI the way you want (in its .xib file)

Then go to your main view controller's file and make an `IBAction` for that button.

In that method, write:

```
 SecondView* second = [[SecondView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2, height, width);
 [self.view addSubview:second.view];
```

This will add it to the bottom half of the screen. Put your own parameters for its height and width. When you want to dismiss the view, you can do this inside your `SecondView` class

```
[self.view removeFromSuperview];
```

You can deal with the textFields from within the `SecondView` class and have them communicate with your other view by doing the following in `SecondView.h`

```
@property IBOutlet UITextField* textField;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming you are using Interface Builder, go ahead and build the overlapping view and hook up all of the IBOutlets and IBActions. Say this view is called `myView`. Set `myView.hidden = YES` and `myView.enabled = NO`. This hides and disables `myView` so that it isn't even there from the user's perspective. In the appropriate button's IBAction, change the `hidden` and `enabled` properties to `YES`. That will make the view visible and active again.